# Issue with button reporducer

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that is supposed to create a new button when clicked, but its not working, I have tried a lot of troubleshooting, and I cant seem to find the issue.  Thanks in advance to any help!

Here is my code I used:

```js
function buttonclick() {
  document.write("<button>test</button");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

  <button onclick=("buttonclick()">test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code.
1) Missing `<html>`
2) Invalid char `(` on `onclick` event bind.

I recomend you to use `appendChild` method available on DOM nodes. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

If you are starting up to code dynamic html take a look on [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body');

function buttonclick() {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body id="body">
  <button onclick="buttonclick()">test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An explanation might help.... ie replacing the erroneous '(' on the click handler.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I've added some explanation.